# How to read a raw signal from a microphone?

Tags: c, linux, audio

`Linux Ubuntu 18.04`
I'm trying to get the raw signal from a microphone as byte sequence and do some signal processing by myself. My first thought was actually just to find a device in the `/dev` directory, open file descriptor and start reading from it. But I discovered that there is audio library [ALSA](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page) which I think does not really provide the ability to read a raw signal from the microphone.

So I found the `/dev/snd` directory and got confused. Here is how it looks like on my machine:

```
/dev/snd$ tree
.
├── by-path
│   ├── pci-0000:00:03.0 -> ../controlC0
│   └── pci-0000:00:1b.0 -> ../controlC1
├── controlC0
├── controlC1
├── hwC0D0
├── hwC1D0
├── pcmC0D3p
├── pcmC0D7p
├── pcmC0D8p
├── pcmC1D0c
├── pcmC1D0p
├── pcmC1D1p
├── pcmC1D2c
├── seq
└── timer
```

How to determine what is the microphone here?

Comment: There should be many good libraries and frameworks which can help you find a suitable input device at run-time, and then let you open and read the raw data from that device. I suggest you try to find such a library or framework instead of attempting to access the device directly.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm doing this for learning purpose. So working with a sound card directly is one of my interest. I tried to open some devices with `O_RDONLY` flag but continiously getting `EBADF` errno. It would be great if you can advice where to start with to learn how to work with devices directly on `Linux`?